# MVC: how to call a non-async method from within a method that has async Task<ActionResult> as the return type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

MVC web app calling methods in a MVC web api.

I have an async method which executes another async method - GetMultiSelections(...).

Both call out to a web api.

They work fine.

However, I added in some new code - the foreach after the 1st method - GetMultiSelections(...).

I encountered an error. So I now want to call another web api method to write the error to a log. It's a non-async method that does not return anything as I don't want anything coming back. (or should I?)

I do this in the 1st Catch. It executes the non-async method but does not go into the web api. I step threw it but it never actually goes into the web api method. I have a break point in the web api and it does not get there.

Is the async preventing it? If so, how to I get the non-async to be executed?

In the non-async method and does the call to the web api - just does not get in there:

[image]

The api method - it does not get here:

[image]

Returned from the non-async method - and throws the error as expected:

[image]

The async method which executes another async method. The both do a call to the web api.:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserProfile()
    {
        UserProfileForMaintVM userProfileForMaintVM = new UserProfileForMaintVM();

        try
        {
            List<UserProfileHoldMulti> userProfileHoldMulti = new List<UserProfileHoldMulti>();

            // Get all the user's multi-selections and the ones he/she did not select.
            userProfileHoldMulti = await GetMultiSelections(Session["UserName"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]));

            foreach (var hold in userProfileHoldMulti)
            {
                switch (hold.ProfileCategoryId)
                {
                    case 25:
                        // Instantiate a new UserProfileMulti25.
                        UserProfileMulti25 userProfileMulti25 = new UserProfileMulti25
                        {
                            SelectionId = hold.SelectionId,
                            ProfileCategoryId = hold.ProfileCategoryId,
                            Description = hold.Description,
                            SelectedSwitch = hold.SelectedSwitch
                        };

                        // Add the multi list to the model's multi list.
                        userProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileMultiList25.Add(userProfileMulti25);

                        break;
                 }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Call the web api to process the error.
            ProcessClientError(Session["UserName"].ToString(), ex.Message, "From method: GetUserProfile. processing multi-selections");

            throw;
        }

        if ((string)@Session["HasProfileSwitch"] == "False")
        {
            return View("UserProfileMaint", userProfileForMaintVM);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                string myIpAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[2].ToString();

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56224");

                    string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/getuserprofile/" + Session["UserName"] + "/" + myIpAddress + "/" + Session["UserId"];

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(restOfUrl);

                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var userResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        userProfileForMaintVM.UserProfileSingleVM = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileSingleVM>(userResponse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.errormessage = "Server error on getting the active userProflie. UserId: " + Session["UserId"] + ". Method: 'GetUserProfile'. Please contact the administrator.";                          
                    }

                    return View("UserProfileMaint", userProfileForMaintVM);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The non-async method:

```
    public void ProcessClientError(string userName, string errorMessage, string additionalInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            string myIpAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[2].ToString();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56224");

                string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/processclienterror/" + Session["UserName"] + "/" + errorMessage + additionalInfo + myIpAddress + "/";

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.GetAsync(restOfUrl);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

GetAsync/PostAsync doesn't necessarily need to call an async method. The GetAsync/PostAsync are the actual async methods wherein once it is called, you have the option to wait for it to finish.

---

**The error I'm seeing is you're calling the webapi with `GetAsync` but in your screenshot the web method `ProcessClientError` is `[HttpPost]`.**

Change `ProcessClientError` data annotation to `[HttpGet]`.

---

Hmm, upon checking again, the url you're trying to access might not match the one you provided in your route. It's missing some slashes `/`.

your current:

```
string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/processclienterror/" + Session["UserName"] + "/" + errorMessage + additionalInfo + myIpAddress + "/";
```

possible fix:

```
string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/processclienterror/" + Session["UserName"] + "/" + errorMessage + "/" + additionalInfo + "/" + myIpAddress + "/";
```

If that still doesnt work, try to url encode the parameters with slashes `/`.

```
string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/processclienterror/" + Session["UserName"] + "/" + errorMessage + "/" + additionalInfo + "/" + Url.Encode(myIpAddress) + "/";
```

Comment: Man I was hoping that was it. But no change in behavior after I changed the web methods data annotation to: [HttpGet]. Still does not get into the web api.

Comment: @user3020047 ohh, let's see if it will get fixed on this next one, haha. I updated the answer.

Comment: LOL - good catch on slashes. I have the slashes on all my other api calls. And they work. I forgot them here. I thought that the "possible fix" one was it. I put them in, but still no go though. Won't go to the api. I did not try the url encoding suggestion as I did not have to do that with the others. Yep stubborn. I'm going to test the call using Postman for now.

Comment: Works fine using Postman: http://localhost:56224/api/profileandblog/processclienterror/DemoUser2/test/other info/32.211.50.62/